# Klipfolio + accuranker json and regex

Tags: json, regex, klipfolio

I'm new at klipfolio,

I have some json data from accuranker. How to I add a condition at the root with regex. Like how do I select keyword where id is 21049316?

[image: json]

Answer (score 0):

@/keyword[preceding-sibling::id=21049316]​

Comment: Code only answers are low quality and subject to deletion, there should always be at least one descriptive sentence describing what question you are answering and how this answer addresses that question.